# Create n EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to repeat the creation of objects in a layout. 
example 
I have a layout with an EditText and I want to create 50 EditText, how can I do without writing 50 in the xml file?

and once done, how can I read the data without creating 50 variables in java?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the activity you could create a layout then use a for loop to add the views eg LineatLayout mLayout = new LinearLayout(this); for(int i=0;i<51;i++){mLayout.addView(new EditText(this));}

It's then possible too access them using mLayout.getChildAt(index);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Story everything in arraylist like this and use

```
ArrayList<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
Button b = new Button(MyActivity.this);
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
view.addView(b);
list.add(b);
```